# Disable a dates based on day selection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a drop-down selection with days of the week. What I want to happen is  when I change the drop-down is to run the `$scope.disabled()` method. Thereby changing the static number in `date.getDay() === 2` date.

You can see the comments on that `$scope.disabled()` function of what I would like to do.

[Here is a half-working Plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/AHIr0xorrJEBjxcdgGuw?p=preview)

Comment: Did the answer work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/oktW37ZkyYEh2KSwc9mr?p=preview)

In your select element, you're using [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions), so you can use the *select as* part of the expression to have the value of each option set to the id using `ng-options="day.id as day.name for day in daysOfWeek"`.  So now, every time you change the select, the value of selectedDay gets updated and a digest is kicked off.  That means you don't have to watch anything and your disable function can be simplified as follows:

```
$scope.disabled = function(date, mode) {
   var day = angular.isUndefined($scope.selectedDay) ? 0 : $scope.selectedDay;
  if (mode === 'day' && date.getDay() === $scope.selectedDay) {
    return true;
  }
  return;
};
```

I added a check to set the value of day to 0 in case the user hasn't selected a day, but you could alternatively initialize the value of the select with:

```
$scope.selectedDay = 0;
```

Now all of that works, but there's a problem: The datepicker only runs the disabled function when it is rendered and its internal refreshView function is called.  The easiest way I can think to trigger a refresh on the datepicker programmatically is to change its ng-model value.  To do this, I added a function:

```
$scope.triggerDate = function(date) {
  $scope.dt = new Date(date);
}
```

By calling triggerDate on the change event of the select element, we reset the datepicker's value with the currently selected date (so we're not changing the value at all), which is enough to force a refresh in the directive.  So, the final select looks like:

```
<select class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="selectedDay" ng-options="day.id as day.name for day in daysOfWeek" ng-change="triggerDate(dt)"></select>
```